# Angular Pipe reference assets

Tags: angular, pipe, assets

I'm building an Angular 4 `Pipe` to support internationalization. I'd like to publish the pipe as a npm module for others to use as well. The pipe will reference json data that developers put in `/assets/i18n/<lang>.json` files like this:

```
{
  "welcome" : "Welcome",
  "register" : "Register"
}
```

and used as a pipe like this:

```
{{ 'welcome' | i18n }}
```

What's the best way to reference the json files from the imported pipe? When I tried using `require('assets/i18n/' + lang + '.json')`to load the json from an imported module, the path can't be resolved. Should I be using `HttpClient` `get` instead? If so, how do I get the json data to the pipe synchronously?

Thx for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the `HttpClient.get` branch. Here you can use your `i18n` Pipe + `async` Pipe to get final result.

Step one is returning `Observable` at your pipe's transform function.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

transform(input) {
  return this.http.get(...);
}
```

Then using `i18n` pipe along with `async` pipe to subscribe automatically.

```
{{ 'welcome' | i18n | async }}
```

Here a sample **[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/6AkYIOA6yhpfa8JGO0xW?p=preview)**.

Comment: Fantastic. Thx for the quick, succinct and dead-on answer!

Comment: @user2193014 you are welcome, if this answered your problem, please upvote and accept the answer to close the question.

Comment: Thx for the quick answer. Your solution works great. Is there a way for me to allow developers to pass configuration params when setting up the Pipe - for instance what path to use to find the i18n .json files. Or do I basically have to hard-code the path and developers will have to use it?

Comment: @user2193014 you can refer to other modern npm packages such as AngularFire2 to allow developers to set some initialize infomation while importing your module.

Comment: I'm using window.navigator.language to determine what language file to request. If the language file doesn't exist, I want to default to one that is guaranteed. How do I handle a 404 from the HttpClient get when the language file doesn't exist? .catch doesn't seem to work. I tried the following but I think I'm now returning an Observable inside an Observable:

    .map(res => {
        if (res) {
          return res[input]
        } else {
          return this.http.get('assets/i18n/en.json')
            .map(en => {
              return en[input]
            });
        }

Comment: ps - the AngularFire ref was useful - I can basically require that developers add config data to environment.

Comment: @user2193014 you can use `catch` operator to handle any error that may happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153894/discussion-between-user2193014-and-pengyy).